# Uploading APK and Expansion Files to GooglePlay

Tags: apk, hybrid-mobile-app, apk-expansion-files, icenium, google-play

I am using Telerik AppBuilder (former Icenium) to build an APK for PlayStore. However, my app is bigger than 50MB, therefore I have to use Expansion Files.

Since files are in cloud, I have pushed them to my Github account, then pulled them, and I created Expansion Files successfully.

I have found a way how to upload Expansion File to Google Playstore, using "placeholder" (dummy) APK.

The problem is, this all doesnt help me much because I have to somehow replace this "placeholder" APK with my actual APK, that is bigger than 50 MB?

Do I need to make my APK smaller than 50MB? Can I just exclude files from my project?

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need to know about using expansion files for an app of yours that exceeds 50 Mb is detailed in the Google Play documentation here: http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html. No need for "placeholder" apks, or replacing apks, the expansion files serve this very purpose.

If you project exceeds the 50 Mb limit with just a little bit, you might consider hosting some of its resources on a server and getting those via ajax requests on demand (whenever an user goes to a view where you need those resources).

If you have high res images or videos, you can compress them and this would reduce size as well.

Comment: that is exactly what I am doing... but have you tried uploading an APK that is bigger than 50MB? You cannot upload expansion files unless you first upload "placeholder" dummy APK. https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2481797

Comment: you need an .apk that complies with the 50 MB limit, everything above that should be in the expansion files.